# Any plans to update Linux kernel in Mendel OS?

Tags: google-coral

The reference distribution for the Google Coral AI board is Mendel OS, which seems to be running a 4.14.x Linux kernel (based on inspecting https://coral.googlesource.com/).

Mendel OS seems to be based on Linux 4.14.98_2.2.0 BSP from IMX.

Are there plans to upgrade the Linux kernel (and in turn the IMX BSP?) The latest IMX BSP seems to be Linux 5.15.5_1.0.0.

Thank you :)